# Find minimum distance to US coastline in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, distance, geopandas, shapely

I have the following code in Python:

```
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
us = world[world['name']=='United States of America'].dissolve(by='name')
coastline = gpd.clip(gpd.read_file('./data/ne_coastline/ne_10m_coastline.shp').to_crs('EPSG:4326'), us)
coastline.distance(Point(30.121735, -81.735374)).min()

# 153.78644123108657
```

But upon manually examination in Google Maps, this isn't correct.  To simplify the problem, I found the coordinate approximating the closest coastline point `(30.135054573782618, -81.34892671159952)`.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

points_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [Point(30.135054573782618, -81.34892671159952), Point(30.121735, -81.735374)]}, crs='EPSG:4326')
points_df = points_df.to_crs('EPSG:3087') # https://epsg.io/3087
points_df2 = points_df.shift() # shift the dataframe by 1 to align points
points_df.distance(points_df2)

# 0            NaN
# 1    4872.316273
# dtype: float64
```

But this is also far off from the correct answer in meters (which I double check manually in Google Maps):

```
from geopy.distance import distance
distance((30.135054573782618, -81.34892671159952), (30.121735, -81.735374)).m

# 37268.01227017112
```

I imagine my coordinate reference system is incorrect, but I'm unsure why [given the reported accuracy of EPSG:3087](https://epsg.io/3087).  How can I correctly output the minimum distance to the coastline in meters given a coordinate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're measuring the distance from Antarctica to the US coastline (in decimal degrees in your first example)...

Unless you mean `Point(-81.735374, 30.121735)`? which is in Florida.

`Point(coords)` uses x, y ordering so you need `Point(longitude, latitude)`

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

points_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'geometry': [
        Point(-81.34892671159952, 30.135054573782618), 
        Point(-81.735374, 30.121735)]}, crs='EPSG:4326')

points_df = points_df.to_crs('EPSG:3087') # https://epsg.io/3087
points_df2 = points_df.shift() # shift the dataframe by 1 to align points

points_df.distance(points_df2)
```

Output:

```
0             NaN
1    37219.622729
dtype: float64
```

And based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32662259/737471), you could do something like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

def min_distance(point, lines):
    return lines.distance(point).min()

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
us = world[world['name']=='United States of America'].dissolve(by='name')
coastline = gpd.clip(gpd.read_file('ne_10m_coastline.shp'), us).to_crs('EPSG:3087')
points_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'geometry': [
        Point(-81.34892671159952, 30.135054573782618), 
        Point(-81.735374, 30.121735)]}, crs='EPSG:4326')
points_df = points_df.to_crs('EPSG:3087') # https://epsg.io/3087

points_df['min_dist_to_coast'] = points_df.geometry.apply(min_distance, args=(coastline,))
```